# Enable to installing GPU drivers on VMs on Google Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, nvidia

I created VM instance on Google Cloud with Ubuntu 18.04 and GPU:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                   
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to install GPU drivers on VMs using [Google Cloud Guides](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu)  to install CUDA 11 and the associated drivers for NVIDIA® GPUs with following commands

```
$wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
$sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
$sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys 
$https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
$sudo add-apt-repository "deb 
$https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

but it failed with following message:

```
>Reading package lists... Done
>Building dependency tree       
>Reading state information... Done
>Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>or been moved out of Incoming.
>The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
>The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>cuda : Depends: cuda-11-4 (>= 11.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
>E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Сan anyone help with solving this problem?

Upd: after creating a new instance, the problem was resolved

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed previous nvidia drivers or deficient cuda toolkit, like some previously versions from the Ubuntu's repository, so you should remove them first.

```
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge cuda
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then install cuda:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help and after 'purge' no files have been removed